# DragTargets within ReorderableListView do not work

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and trying to work out if there's a way to have DragTargets within a ReorderableListView? I've seen a few suggestions on here that DragTargets don't work within the ReorderableListView widget, but no details as to why or workarounds.

What I'm trying to achieve is having a ReorderableListView with a FloatingActionButton that can be dragged in between list items and it insert a new list item at that location.

Is this possible? Any widgets exists that do this already?

Thanks

ReorderableListView so far:

```
return Scaffold(
        body: ReorderableListView(
            onReorder: reorderData,
            children: items.map((item) {
              return Container(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  child: Card(
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      elevation: 1,
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          item["icon"],
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          item["name"],
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        trailing: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => item['route']));
                        },
                      )));
            }).toList())
```

Example items list:

```
List items = [
  {
    "icon": Icons.check_box_outline_blank_outlined,
    "name": "Test",
    "route": null
  },
  {
    "icon": Icons.check_box_outline_blank_outlined,
    "name": "Test",
    "route": null
  },
];
```

:[image: ReorderableListView]